# Make a required field if the other field has value

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, controller, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have these variables:

```
public int? BossId { get; set; }
public DateTime? HeadShipDate { get; set; }
```

My view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BossId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("BossId", null, "-- Select --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BossId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div id="divDate" class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HeadShipDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
     <div class="col-md-10">
         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HeadShipDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HeadShipDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
     </div>
</div>
```

Script (What I was trying to make required if BossId has a value):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        HeadShipDate: {
                required: {
                    depends: function(element){
                        return $("#BossId").text() != '-- Select --';
                    }
                }
        }
</script>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Acronym,Percentage,BossId,HeadShipDate")] Department department)
{
    Seller boss = db.Sellers.Find(department.BossId);
    if (boss.AdmissionDate > department.HeadShipDate)
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Headship Date (" + department.HeadShipDate.Value.ToShortDateString() + ") must be greater than the Admission Date (" + boss.AdmissionDate.ToShortDateString() + ") of boss");
    else if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        boss.DeptId = department.Id;
        db.Departments.Add(department);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.BossId = new SelectList(SellersNonBosses(), "Id", "Name", department.BossId);
    return View(department);
 }
```

I want to make the HeadShipDate required field IF BossId has a value, in other works, if the text of DropDownList isn't "-- Select --", AND I want to make that validation (that condition I made in controller, checking headship date with admissionDate of that specific seller(Boss)) with JavaScript, how can I make this?

Comment: What's wrong with the thing that's "working fine"?

Comment: I'm not asking about the script 1, i'm just showing my code, I'm looking for solution to script 2 and a script example to make that validation (in controller) wth JS. Did you undertand now? Btw, I'll edit..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing [IValidatableObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on your view model allows for greater control over ad-hoc validation rules like this.

## Example

```
public class Department : IValidatableObject
{
    public int? BossId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? HeadShipDate { get; set; }
    ...

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate( ValidationContext validationContext )
    {
        if( BossId.HasValue && !HeadShipDate.HasValue )
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult( "HeadShipDate is required if BossId is selected.", new[] { "HeadShipDate" } );
        }
    }
}
```

Then you only need to check `ModelState.IsValid` in your controller action.

**Note:** This only applies server side validation to the ModelState. If you want client side validation as well you will need to implement a Javascript function that does something similar prior to submitting the form.

Example:

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        HeadShipDate: {
            required: {
                depends: function (element) {
                    return $("#BossId").val() != '';
                }
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        HeadShipDate: {
            required: "Please specify the Headship Date"
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I was asking for client side validation, anyway, ModelState.IsValid will call this class "MyViewModel" automatically? Did you have look my script 2? What am I missing? [To make headShip required if BossId has a value].. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, `ModelState` will automatically have the results of `MyViewModel`s `Validate` method.

Comment: Can you post your view model class?

Comment: I created a class, as u posted here, named MyViewModel, I just have model, controller and views, and now this new class.

Comment: This new class is your model that should be wired up to your view and controller. There should not be two models.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79043/discussion-between-kspearrin-and-developer033).

Comment: Updated answer to be complete with server side AND client side validation for this scenario.

Comment: Yeah, this client side validation which I sent to you, is working, now I just need the client side validation to checking dates (that validation I wrote in my controller]. Thanks for the server side validation, it works too.

Comment: I'll accept, but, my original question isn't answered for complete, I asked 2 things.. anyway, Accepted!